# How to overcome the class imbalance issue in a text classification problem?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, svm

The dataset has 5 labels A,B,C,D,E

A,B,C are majority and D&E are minority.The penalty to misclassify D&E are huge. How can I implement a cost sensitive learning. The input to the model will be english sentences like user comments.

Comment: Can you put up a ratio or percentages of the class representation in your data?

Comment: Just multiply the loss for samples from D,E by their relative importance to A,B,C.

Comment: A: 57% B: 17% C:18% D:5% E: 3%

Answer (score 2):

Option 1: play with the thresholds for classifying something – perhaps you could set a threshold for classifying something as a minority class should even if it doesn't have the highest probability/score, or a ratio of probabilities/thresholds.

Option 2: upsample your data (take resamples with replacement of the minority classes until they have as many observations as the others).

Option 3: use some cost-sensitive algorithm (e.g. some forms of classification trees) - probably won't translate into very accurate results.